# How to make titled border for RadioGroup in Android?

Tags: android, border

As in the title - is it possible to make a titled border around RadioGroup? Or at least a plain border ...
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a screen shot of what you want or a better explanation? Have you tried to make one at all?

Comment: I asked this question having in mind the titledBorder you can do in Java Swing.  I tried to look for methods for this purpose but could not find one. Btw I have just began learning android

Answer (score 2):

Titled border, I don't know...You might want to just add a TextView        widget above the border.
But for a plain border, here's how I put a border around my radio group:
Here is my basic radio group (has three buttons, horizontal)

```
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/myRadioLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:elevation="24dp">

    <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioBtn1"
        android:text="RadioButton1" android:checked="true"
        style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
        android:textSize="14sp">
    </RadioButton>



    <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioBtn2"
        android:text="RadioButton2"
        style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
        android:textSize="14sp">
    </RadioButton>

    <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioBtn3"
        android:text="RadioButton3" android:checked="true"
        style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
        android:textSize="14sp">
    </RadioButton>  
</RadioGroup>
```

So, if I want a border surrounding my radio button group, I add an xml file to my drawable folder. Let's call it "border.xml".
Here is the code for border.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

Then, you add the following code to your radio group xml:

```
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/myRadioLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:elevation="24dp">
```

And a border should appear around your radio group. Note that you can vary the attributes to get different shapes for the border, gradients, rounded corners, etc. possible attributes for the shape element, can be found here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: Thanks.  This worked partially for me.  The border is drawn around most of the radiogroup, but where the actual radiobuttons are drawn they obscure the radiogroup's border.  In other words, the border is either not drawn or when the individual radio button is drawn it paints over the border.